# print foreach loop with json_encode in php

Tags: php, foreach

I am new to php. so it may be very basic but I don't know it. So, I want to output like this in php using json_encode().

```
"option": [
    {
      "poOptionGroup": "11",
      "optGrpID": "11",
      "optGrpName": "Choose Backing Material"
    },
    {
      "optID": "40",
      "optName": "Black (Plexiglass)",
      "optPriceDiff": "0"
    },
    {
      "optID": "41",
      "optName": "Clear (Plexiglass)",
      "optPriceDiff": "18"
    },
    {
      "optID": "218",
      "optName": "Neon Stand Off",
      "optPriceDiff": "18"
    },
    {
      "optID": "219",
      "optName": "White Plastic",
      "optPriceDiff": "18"
    }
  ],
  "option": [
    {
      "poOptionGroup": "13",
      "optGrpID": "13",
      "optGrpName": "Any notes you want to include with your order"
    },
    {
      "optID": "174",
      "optName": "NO Thanks",
      "optPriceDiff": "0"
    },
    {
      "optID": "175",
      "optName": "YES OUTDOOR",
      "optPriceDiff": "170"
    }
  ],
  "SPIN3": [
    {
      "poOptionGroup": "56",
      "optGrpID": "56",
      "optGrpName": "Upgrade to OUTDOOR"
    },
    {
      "optID": "44",
      "optName": "",
      "optPriceDiff": "20.02"
    }
  ]
```

for this I have two nested foreach loop. which is as below:

```
$product=array();   
        foreach($query as $q){
            $product['optGrpID']= $q['optGrpID'];
            $product['optGrpName'] = $q['optGrpName'];
            $product['poOptionGroup'] = $q['poOptionGroup'];
            $opt_id=$product['optGrpID'];
                $string=  sql("select optID, optName, optPriceDiff from options where optGroup='$opt_id' ");
                foreach ($string as $k=>$s){
                    $product['options']['optID']=$s['optID'];
                    $product['options']['optName']=$s['optName'];
                    $product['options']['optPriceDiff']=$s['optPriceDiff'];
                }
        }
```

so how can I achieve this desired output? please help. any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Hey @softech - I am just interested whether my answer was of any help to you? Do you need further assistance on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am right in the proces of writing a PHP JSON API so I came across similar problems in the past few days. While I can't / don't want to solve your particular question about the PHP code, here is the most important thing I learned that I didn't find in many documentations or tutorials:

Giving `json_encode()` an associative array produces an JSON object with `{key: value, key: value, ...}`. Giving it a non-associative array produces a JSON list with `[value, value, value, ...]`. The values in the latter version can off course be objects them self (`{...}`). This means to get the structure you want, you have to pass the following array to json_encode:

```
array(
    "option" => array(
        array(
            "optId" => "40",
            "optName": "Black (Plexiglass)",
            "optPriceDiff": "0"
        ),
        array(
            "optId" => "40",
            "optName": "Black (Plexiglass)",
            "optPriceDiff": "0"
        ),
        .......
    ),
    "SPIN3" => array(
        array(
            "poOptionGroup" => "56",
            "optGrpID" => "56",
            "optGrpName" => "Upgrade to OUTDOOR"
        ),
        array(
            "optID" => "44",
            "optName" => "",
            "optPriceDiff" => "20.0"
        )
    )
);
```

As you can see, some of those arrays are associative arrays, some of them are non-associative arrays acting as a "simple list". Knowing this, it should be easy to modify your PHP code to produce an array like the above and pass it to `json_encode()`. Unless you force `json_encode()` to allways produce JSON objects with a flag, PHP handles the conversion to JSON objects and JSON lists as seen above.

For correct terminology: "list" refers to JSON arrays, whereas associative arrays are converted to JSON objects with string-value-links. See the [JSON website](http://www.json.org/) for details.